# Powershell - Copy folders with names matching array

Tags: sql, powershell, filter

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish

1. run sql query - result output to txt file
2. results of txt file to array
3. get child item- folders and files in the directory if the folder name matches a value from the array
4. copy items that are returned in step 3 to another directory

The problem I am having is filtering the items in the directory based on the values of the array

```
gci $sourcepath -recurse | where {$_.name -like $idlist} | Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationHistoryPath
```

Comment: What is `$idlist`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'll echo what @zett42 has said.  I'll go one step further and ask if you've checked into the `-in` comparison?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've already loaded up the array properly.  You don't want the `-like` operator for this particular scenario.  You are better off with `-in` or `-Contains`. Something like below may work:

```
Get-ChildItem $sourcepath -Recurse | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -in $idlist} | 
Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationHistoryPath
```

If you use contains you'll need to switch the operands like:

```
Get-ChildItem $sourcepath -recurse | 
Where-Object { $idlist -contains $_.Name } | 
Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationHistoryPath
```